# Golang iris sessions are not persistent

Tags: session, go, session-cookies

I'm stuck on getting sessions to work in GoLang.  Specifically within Iris.

Calling a route with "Login" will print out a token; then when I call a route with Restricted, the token is empty.  Am I doing something wrong or do I misunderstand the concept behind sessions in GoLang?

```
func Login(c *iris.Context) {
    username := c.FormValueString("email")
    password := c.FormValueString("password")
    test := "unauthorized"
    if username == "jon@snow.com" && password == "123abc!@#" {
        token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
            "name": "Jon Snow",
            "exp": time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 72).Unix(),
        })

        t, err := token.SignedString([]byte("SecretKey"))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        c.Session().Set("token", t)
        test = c.Session().GetString("token")
    }

    c.Text(200, test)
}



func Restricted(c *iris.Context) {  
    tokenString := c.Session().GetString("token")
    if tokenString != "" {
        c.Text(iris.StatusOK, tokenString)
    } else {
        c.Text(iris.StatusOK, "no Token")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the session package first `go get "github.com/kataras/iris/sessions"`
then create a session with `var sess = sessions.New(sessions.Config{Cookie: "cookie-name" })`[read this documentation to see how this work](https://docs.iris-go.com/sessions.html)